# Rake migration aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rake

I'm running Ruby 2.0.0 and I installed it correctly. Just loaded up a gem 'devise' and as I tried to migrate my database changes, it wouldn't work:

> $ rake db:migrate
>   rake aborted!
>   `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.

Then, following another Stackoverflow post, they recommended installing Bundler. I did that successfully and got this:

> $ bundle exec rake db:migrate
>   rake aborted!
>   `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.

Is anyone up to the challenge to help?

Comment: Since it seems like you are new to Rails, if you want to learn with Rails 4 I suggest taking a look at [Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0) which now covers Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use Rails 4.0.0beta which is not (IMHO) the best choice for a newbie. You’d better switch back to Rails 3* and yield all the advantages of well-documented, tested rock-n-rolling environment.
If you still decide to stick to Rails 4… Previously there were no strict rules to deal with mass-assignment. Rails 4 standardises this with **Strong Parameters**, which has been merged into rails core. Thus, you are to do smth like:

```
# controllers/my_controller.rb
def create
    @app = MyApp.new(my_params)
  if @app.save
    redirect_to app_path(@app)
  else
    render :new, alert: 'There was a problem'
  end
end

private

def my_params
  params.require(:app).permit(:title, :password)
end
```

The assignment logic is now being encapsulated in a private method to permit certain values to act as params.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Devise 3.0.0.rc, which supports Rails 4.

You will need to:

- Revert the changes and delete the files generated by older version of Devise.
- Update `Gemfile`:

  ```
  gem 'devise', '3.0.0.rc'
  ```
- Run `bundle install`.
- Regenerate Devise initializer and migrations.